# nginx closed the connection to upstream and return 502

Tags: php, nginx

I use nginx do load balance in the frontend and the backend are docker instance also with nginx+php-fpm;

The problem is that my backend nginx return 499, and the frontend nginx return 502;

I think that is because the frontend nginx closed the connection;

But the frontend nginx's keepalive_timeout=65; 
also the  proxy_connect_timeout=6,
but when return 502 ,the log show that

```html
"3.002" "10.154.30.153:31010" "502" "3.002"

log_format:
'"$request_time" "$upstream_addr" "$upstream_status" "$upstream_response_time"';
```

Since the `$upstream_response_time` is 3.002. Why does it return the code 502?
Hope you can help me to analyse, thank you so much!